# Нужна ли запятая? 1

Tags: пунктуация

Каким правилом нужно здесь руководствоваться при постановке или непостановке запятой?

*С английского название этого фантастически уютного места переводится(,) как слива.*

Comment: @МатвейДёмин зачем вы изменяете исходное предложение? Стоит указать о недочете в комментариях или в ответе.

Comment: Там было " в переводе с английского... переводится..." В данном случае вопрос нужно тоже редактировать.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин Тогда уж стоит об этом написать где-нибудь. Вроде бы на вопросы в ответах отвечают, а предложения пишут в комментариях.  Ну а редактируют, чтобы вопрос можно было лучше понять, чтобы он выглядел не сумбурно.

Comment: Дело в том, что в данном случае человек просит объяснить, нужна или не нужна запятая, а само предложение при этом построено безграмотно. Убираем безграмотность и концентрируемся на запятой, ведь нас только о ней спрашивали... А писать об этом негде.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин в P. S. или после "кстати" ;) почему негде?

Comment: Aer, где, по-вашему, нужно об этом написать? Если этот момент для Вас так принципиален, попробуйте его сформулировать и задать остальным членам сообщества. Других вариантов я не знаю.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин по моему мнению, не надо изменять заданный вопрос кардинально (а удаление чего бы то ни было из предложения, по которому вопрос, есть как раз это)

Comment: Мы с вами не придём к единому мнению, Aer. Если хотите, восстанавливайте безграмотный исходный вариант текста.

Answer (score 1):

Да, ошибка есть: запятая перед *как* лишняя.

Вот правило: **Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла, например: Она держится как хозяйка.**
Подробнее: http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

Кстати, в предложении есть тавтология (в **переводе**... **переводится**). Возможно, его стоит переформулировать.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не только "с запятой" ошибка, есть и грамматическая(название мест**а**), и речевая : в переводе ...переводится.

Нужно или"В переводе с английского название этого фантастически уютного мест**а** **означает**  слива", или "С английского название этого фантастически уютного мест**а** переводится как слива".

О правиле пунктуации в этом случае Вам ответили.

Comment: А кавычки не надо при "сливе"?